# How can have a conditional template tag based on the main loop within a secondary loop with new WP_Query(), using get_template_part()

Tags: loop, conditional-tags, get-template-part

What is the best practice methodology for referencing the main loop from within the context of a secondary loop within a partial called via get_template_part()?

For example, say my homepage contains a secondary loop to list two posts of type article:

```
<?php
$articles = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'posts_per_page' => 2
) );
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php
            while ( $articles->have_posts() ) : $articles->the_post();
                get_template_part( 'templates/listing', 'article');
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </ul>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

And in /templates/listing-article.php, I have:

```
<?php if (!is_front_page()) : ?>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here, the_content() lists the content of the article as expected/intended.  is_front_page() returns false as expected, but not as intended - my intention is to show the content if on any page except the homepage.

My question is thus: how does one make conditional template tags like is_front_page() return true/false based on the post in the main loop, as opposed to my secondary loop.

You could set a global variable in your homepage template that you then reference in your partial, but I'm asking if there's a standard, better solution.

Comment: The home page and front page are not always the same. is_home() returns true on the posts page according to your reading settings and is_front_page() always returns true for the front page regardless of your reading settings

Comment: Note that your line 6 should read `if ( $articles->have_posts() ) :` (not `$posts`). But this is most likely not your actual code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *ask* the main query directly (which is, in fact, exactly what the `is_front_page` function is doing).

```
<?php global $wp_query; ?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you altered the main query, however, refer to the *backup*.

```
<?php global $wp_the_query; ?>
<?php if ( $wp_the_query->is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```